# ResNet50 input issue for feature extraction in Keras

Tags: python-3.x, keras, computer-vision, resnet

I am using a pre-trained Resnet50 model for simple feature extraction for images. but it gives me this error.

```
Error when checking input: expected input_9 to have the shape (224, 224, 3) but got array with shape (244, 244, 3)
```

I thought I changed the shape correctly and added a dimension to it like this tutorial said to do. https://www.kaggle.com/kelexu/extract-resnet-feature-using-keras

But it still gives me the above error.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
# load pre-trained resnet50
base_model = ResNet50(weights='imagenet', include_top=False,pooling=max)
x = base_model.output
input = Input(shape=(224,224,3))
x = Flatten()(input)
model = Model(inputs=input, outputs=x)
# Load in image
img = image.load_img("001.png", target_size=(244, 244))
x = image.img_to_array(img)
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
x = preprocess_input(x)
print(x.shape) # This produces (1, 244, 244, 3)
features  = model.predict(x)
features_reduce =  features.squeeze()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

`img = image.load_img("001.png", target_size=(244, 244))`

to

`img = image.load_img("001.png", target_size=(224, 224))`

Comment: I see a miss type. Thank you I been stuck on this for about an hour now.

Comment: This took me 5 minutes to see. Difference is `244` vs `224` in the target_size argument